# How to push graph to Apollo Graph Manager with travis and docker

Tags: docker, kubernetes, travis-ci, apollo

I am working on Apollo Federation. So far, I have successfully deployed my services to google kubernetes cluster using travis.

The only remaining issue is, including the `apollo service:push --serviceURL=http://auth-cluster-ip-service --serviceName=auth` script in my CI/CD. But I have no idea how.. Its my first time setting up CI/CD.

My working travis config file without `apollo service:push` is:

```
sudo: required
services:
  - docker
env:
  global:
    - SHA=$(git rev-parse HEAD)
    - CLOUDSDK_CORE_DISABLE_PROMPTS=1
language: node_js
node_js:
  - 10
before_install:
  - openssl aes-256-cbc -K $encrypted_9f3b5599b056_key -iv $encrypted_9f3b5599b056_iv -in service-account.json.enc -out service-account.json -d
  - curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash > /dev/null;
  - source $HOME/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc
  - gcloud components update kubectl
  - gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file service-account.json
  - gcloud config set project salading-production
  - gcloud config set compute/zone asia-northeast3-a
  - gcloud container clusters get-credentials salading-cluster
  - echo "$SHA"
  - echo "$DOCKER_PASSWORD" | docker login -u "$DOCKER_USERNAME" --password-stdin
script:
  - echo "skipping tests"
deploy:
  provider: script
  script: bash ./deploy.sh
  on:
    branch: master
```

Below is the `deploy.sh` file:

```
docker build -t hoffnung8493/salading-auth:latest -t hoffnung8493/salading-auth:$SHA .
docker push hoffnung8493/salading-auth:latest
docker push hoffnung8493/salading-auth:$SHA
kubectl apply -f k8s
kubectl set image deployment/auth-deployment auth=hoffnung8493/salading-auth:$SHA
```

I tried adding two lines in `deploy.sh`:

```
npm i -g apollo
apollo service:push --serviceURL=http://auth-cluster-ip-service --serviceName=auth --endpoint=http://auth-cluster-ip-service
```

and got following errors:

```
Loading Apollo Project [started]
Loading Apollo Project [completed]
Uploading service to Apollo Graph Manager [started]
Fetching info from federated service
Uploading service to Apollo Graph Manager [failed]
→ request to http://auth-cluster-ip-service/ failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND auth-cluster-ip-service auth-cluster-ip-service:80
FetchError: request to http://auth-cluster-ip-service/ failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND auth-cluster-ip-service auth-cluster-ip-service:80
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (~/.nvm/versions/node/v10.19.0/lib/node_modules/apollo/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:1455:11)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, while I was typing my own question in stackoverflow, I came up with the solution. Since, I already finished typing my question, I decided to share the solution.

It turns out an easy solution is simply adding 5 lines of code in `after_deploy` in `.travis.yml` file. 
`npm run dev &`: this runs the node server in background
Afterwards `sleep 3` gives the server some time to turn on.
Finally the last code pushes the new graphql schema to Apollo Graph Manager. 
Note that in your travis-ci.com's settings, you have to add apollo's `ENGINE_API_KEY` as environment variable. Also note that your node server can print out some connection errors. In my case I did not provide, redis and mongodb connection related environment variables. But as long as the server itself is running for introspection, `apollo service:push` will work fine.

```
sudo: required
services:
  - docker
env:
  global:
    - SHA=$(git rev-parse HEAD)
    - CLOUDSDK_CORE_DISABLE_PROMPTS=1
language: node_js
node_js:
  - 10
before_install:
  - openssl aes-256-cbc -K $encrypted_9f3b5599b056_key -iv $encrypted_9f3b5599b056_iv -in service-account.json.enc -out service-account.json -d
  - curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash > /dev/null;
  - source $HOME/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc
  - gcloud components update kubectl
  - gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file service-account.json
  - gcloud config set project salading-production
  - gcloud config set compute/zone asia-northeast3-a
  - gcloud container clusters get-credentials salading-cluster
  - echo "$SHA"
  - echo "$DOCKER_PASSWORD" | docker login -u "$DOCKER_USERNAME" --password-stdin
script:
  - echo "skipping tests"
deploy:
  provider: script
  script: bash ./deploy.sh
  on:
    branch: master
after_deploy:
  - npm install
  - npm i -g apollo
  - npm run dev &
  - sleep 3
  - apollo service:push --serviceURL=http://auth-cluster-ip-service --serviceName=auth --endpoint=http://localhost:3051
```